Proving smallest equivalence relation
Suppose $R$ is a reflexive and symmetric relation on a finite set $A$. Define a  relation $S$ on $A$ by declaring $xSy$ if and only if for some  $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there are elements $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n \in A$ satisfying $xRx_1, x_1Rx_2, \cdots, x_{n-1}Rx_n$ and $x_nRy$. Show that $S$ is an equivalence relation and $R \subseteq S$. Prove that $S$ is the unique smallest equivalence relation on $A$ containing $R$.
Now, I have proven all things here except the last part where I have to prove that $S$ is the smallest equivalence relation on  $A$ containing $R$. So, if there is another equivalence relation on $A$ containing $R$, then I have to prove that $S \subseteq T$. Is this correct ? But, how do I go about proving this ?

Let $T$ be an equivalence relation on $A$ such that $R \subseteq T$.
Then $S \subseteq T$:
If $(x,y) \in S$, then there exists $n \in \Bbb N$ and $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n \in A$ such that $(x,x_1),(x_1,x_2),\dots,(x_n,y)$ belongs to $R$.
Hence, $(x,x_1),(x_1,x_2),\dots,(x_n,y)$ belongs to $T$, and then $(x,y) \in T$ since $T$ is transitive.
Therefore, $S \subseteq T$.
